Is there a way to merge two calligraphic strokes while keeping the brush settings of each stroke in Illustrator?
Is there is a way to merge these two calligraphic brush strokes while keeping each strokes unique brush settings and just smoothly combining them without expanding appearance?
I know the width tool doesn't work for calligraphic strokes. Is my best bet to just use a basic stroke and use the width tool to match what I want?


No, what do you envision to achieve with this though? Whats wrong with grouping?

A calligraphy brush is generally supposed to simulate a fixed width nib, at fixed angles.  What you want to do is more like what you would get with a nib that flexes and widens depending on how much pressure is applied to the pen, like the kind used for copperplate style handwriting.  Yes, I think your best bet would be to use a normal stroke, and use the width tool - or alternatively use a graphics tablet with stylus, where you can modify the stroke thickness depending on how hard you press.

It's possible to assign stylus pressure to affect the size of a calligraphy brush. However this is tricky to use, and I haven't had much success doing this. I usually go down the Width Tool route.

Thanks everyone for your responses. I need practice with the graphic tablet so I just wanted to check to see if I was overlooking an alternative without using a tablet. I guess this is a good time to get some practice with a tablet in!

No. There's no way to "combine" brush strokes, but keep the existing appearance on separate strokes once they are combined.
The only way to combine brush strokes it to ...

Join the paths, which means the brush profile will change to match the entire length of the now unified path.
Expand the appearance and use Pathfinder/Shape Builder to combine the expanded shapes - Losing all actual brush strokes.

Sorry, you can't join separate brush stroke paths without altering the brush profile itself or expanding the appearance to shapes.

Possibly the best solution, for a Calligraphy Brush appearance, is to use a standard stroke and then utilize the Width Tool to alter that strokes profile, matching the separate calligraphic brush strokes.

As I expected. Thanks for your answer!
